# How do I copy distinct divs using javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

I can only use CSS, Javascript, and HTML. I am trying to have a table laid out similar to blog posts. Post 1, post 2, etc...

I am trying to ad a "copy text" button to each post and have it copy that specific posts content. I thought I had it all figure out but it's not working. It copies only 1 div no matter which button I click.

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  CONTENT I WANT COPIED - POST 1
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')">Click To Copy</button>

<div id="div2">
  CONTENT I WANT COPIED - POST 2
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div2')">Click To Copy</button>
```

What's happening is it's only copying one of the posts no matter which button

Comment: You create a textRange but you do not erase it. Thats causing issue

Comment: ok this is amazing and thank you for a quick response! bonus ... do you know how I can automatically change the text of the button to go to "copied" ... once it is clicked? I didn't like the alert i had but was stuck with it

Comment: button has a text property. Just set it to new text. You will easily find it on SO

Comment: yea i was looking and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the selection range before you add another

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    var sel = window.getSelection()
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    console.log("Copied!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  CONTENT I WANT COPIED - POST 1
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')">Click To Copy</button>

<div id="div2">
  CONTENT I WANT COPIED - POST 2
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div2')">Click To Copy</button>
```

Comment: ok this is amazing and thank you for a quick response!

bonus ... do you know how I can automatically change the text of the button to go to "copied" ... once it is clicked? I didn't like the alert i had but was stuck with it.